# Wait for Bulk Insert stored procedure to finish

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, .net-core

I have a stored procedure which actually bulk inserts entries into the database and after it finishes, it returns the output parameter.

When I call my procedure from my .NET Core web application, it does not wait for the procedure to finish and redirects the page in the next step. How can I make my code wait for the stored procedure to finish?

Note: the stored procedure works perfectly alright when run from SQL Server Management Studio, and if I put a breakpoint in my action method.

Here is how I am calling my stored procedure;

```
public IActionResult Import(ImportTransactionsVM TransactionsVM)
{
    int ReportResult = 0;

    DataPathParam = new SqlParameter("@pDataFilePath", FilesHandlerHelper.ImportFile(_hostingEnvironment, TransactionsVM.ReportFile));
    FileTypeParam = new SqlParameter("@pFileType", TransactionsVM.BankType);
    OutputParam = new SqlParameter("@pOutputValue", SqlDbType.Int)
    {
        //Direction of this parameter is output.
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
        Value = 0
    };

    FormatPathParam = new SqlParameter("@pFormatFilePath", Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Data\\ImportFormats\\MigsReport.fmt"));

    ReportResult = _dbContext.Database
        .ExecuteSqlRaw("exec SP_ImportTransactionReports @pDataFilePath, @pFormatFilePath, @pFileType, @pOutputValue OUT", DataPathParam, FormatPathParam, FileTypeParam, OutputParam);
                    
    return RedirectToAction("Import", new { result = OutputParam.Value });
}
```

I have also used `ExecuteSqlRawAsync` with `await` with the same results.

Also, the stored procedure is actually bulk inserting the records.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds unlikely.  What evidence do you have that it "does not wait for the procedure to finish and redirects the page"?  Can you produce a short, self-contained repro?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft it just redirects to Import action without the result parameter. but if i debug it, it populates the table as well as output parameter as expected.

Comment: Perhaps something else is causing the stored procedure to not set the output parameter.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was the file being imported was locked when I was copying the file during upload.

So I changed

```
File.CopyTo(new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create));
```

to

```
var _FileStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create);
File.CopyTo(_FileStream);
_FileStream.Close();
```

Thanks to **@David Browne - Microsoft** for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see any FileStream in your code.

Comment: FilesHandlerHelper.ImportFile(_hostingEnvironment, TransactionsVM.ReportFile) is actually uploading the file